# NodeJS async.parallel and mutex

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, mutex

I am trying to build a project with async.parallel but all the parallel functions are modifying the same global variable. How can I put a mutex or some kind of lock on that variable ?

Comment: If you don't want to share the global variable then make it a local variable or change it to a serial processing.

Comment: Show your code or explain exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not handel that in the finish function?

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```